# How to schedule a nightly task in JBoss

Tags: jboss, scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a task to run every night at midnight or 1:00am using JBoss's Scheduler. I can't seem to figure out what parameter I need to adjust that will allow me to run the task every day at midnight.

Here is my current settings (sorry didn;t know how to paste XML code here)...

http://pastebin.com/urTqnNPN

Any ideas on what I need to modify or add in order to schedule my task for midnight?

BTW, I running JBoss 4.3.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At work, I run almost the same JBoss version  and the configuration file varies in these elements:

```xml
<!-- it runs every day at  00:15  -->
<!-- 24hs (24hs x 60 min x 60 seC x 1000 ms = 86400000 ms) -->
<attribute name="InitialStartDate">2011-04-30 00:15:00</attribute> <!-- only hours part is importat here -->
<attribute name="SchedulePeriod">86400000</attribute> 
<attribute name="DateFormat">yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</attribute>
```